# How to show decimal's in code

Tags: vba

```
Dim Cost, Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4, Answer, Answer1, NumberMeals As Decimal
    If rbSingle.Checked Then Number1 = 200.0 
    If rbDouble.Checked Then Number2 = 210
    If rbSuite.Checked Then Number3 = 220
    If rbLuxary.Checked Then Number4 = 50
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then NumberMeals = 10

    Cost = Number1 + Number2 + Number3 + Number4 + NumberMeals
    Answer = Cost * txtDays.Text

    Label5.Text = Answer
    Label5.Visible = True
```

How do I make it show decimals in the label eg $200.00

Comment: just as a side note, VBA doesn't dim everything in that format. only `NumberMeals` is a `Decimal`, everything else is still `Variant`. To fix this you need to dim each individually, this can still be on the same line. `Dim Cost as Decimal, Number1 as Decimal, Number2 as Decimal.....`

Comment: @ballsy26 Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind found out how.

Label5.Text = Format(Answer, "C")